# Mail not being recieved when sent from Ubuntu 14.04 server with postfix on ServerMania

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

I am using postfix to redirect mail to my Gmail.  On my local Ubuntu 14.04 VM instance it works great.  When I try to do it on my Ubuntu 14.04 server on ServerMania with postfix, I see what appears to be the email sent in the mail log, but I never receive it.  Can someone suggest a reason why?

Here is the log entries:

```
*Sep 30 01:01:33 server1 postfix/pickup[2695]: D1BBF220A93: uid=33 from=<my@email.com>*

*Sep 30 01:01:33 server1 postfix/cleanup[2702]: D1BBF220A93: message-id=<90720bee
90a9c92675c794d650d82206@23.236.206.114>*

*Sep 30 01:01:33 server1 postfix/qmgr[2696]: D1BBF220A93: from=<my@email.com>, size=1283, nrcpt=1 (queue active)*

*Sep 30 01:01:34 server1 postfix/smtp[2704]: D1BBF220A93: to=<my@email.com>, orig_to=<redirect@local.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.22.27]:25, dela
y=0.44, delays=0.03/0/0.25/0.16, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1443589382
 m9si24671672qkl.95 - gsmtp)*

*Sep 30 01:01:34 server1 postfix/qmgr[2696]: D1BBF220A93: removed*
```

I have removed the actual email addresses (obviously).  It doesn't seem to error but I never receive any email.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with help of a friend.  Turned out the problem was how I was sending mail to postfix for relay.  I changed the virtual alias from root@something.com to just root.  So entry in /etc/postfix/virtual looks like this now:

*root destination@email.com*

Now when I send email to this alias I send it to root@server1.mydomain.com.  This resolved the issue as I also did not have the correct address specified.  Mail is now being forwarded.  Not sure why it was even attempting to forward if an incorrect forwarding address was present.  Very strange.